# How can I make a single-aligned row under two double-aligned rows in an equation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath, align

I have an equation that I would like to align like this (the x is actually `\times`):

```
A = BBBBB CCCCCCC
          x DDDDD
  = EEEEEEE FFFFF
```

I have tried the align environment, align with nested aligned, and alignat with two columns.

The best I can do with plain align is:

```
A =&~ widersum &BBBBB &CCCCCCC
   &           &      &x DDDDD
  =&~ sum      &BBBBB &FFFFF
```

Which in my current case is fine, because the second sum is only a fraction less wide. But is there any decent way to ignore a second alignment `&` in one row?

PS: I seem to need extra spaces `~` when I place the alignment after an equals sign. How come?

**EDIT:** a realistic example

```
f_ &= \sum_{\mu, \lambda=-\infty}^\infty &blabla bla bla \notag \\
                                         &&\times blabla \notag \\
   &= \sum_{\lambda=-\infty}^\infty blabla bla blabla
```

is what I'm after

Comment: ad "`~` at equals sign": There are two options: `A &= B` or `A = {}& B`, choose whichever you prefer. But `~` will create certaily a too long space.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `alignat` instead of `align`:

[image]

Additionally you could use `\rlap` from the `mathtools` package to not have the last line effect the alignment of the previous lines:

[image]

### Notes:

- I inserted an additional `{}` to ensure that the `\times` is treated as a binary operator.

### Code: `alignat`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
    f &= \sum_{\mu, \lambda=-\infty}^\infty   & blabla bla bla  \notag \\
      &                                       & {}\times blabla \notag \\
      &= \sum_{\lambda=-\infty}^\infty blabla bla blabla
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

### Code: `alignat` and `rlap`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{math tools} % Already includes amsmath

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
    f &= \sum_{\mu, \lambda=-\infty}^\infty   & blabla bla bla  \notag \\
      &                                       & {}\times blabla \notag \\
      &= \rlap{$\displaystyle\sum_{\lambda=-\infty}^\infty blabla bla blabla$}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can do that with alignat:

```
        \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{mathtools}

        \pagestyle{empty}

        \begin{document}

            \begin{subequations}
                \begin{alignat}{2}
                  f_0 & = & \sum_{\mu, \lambda=-\infty}^\infty blabla bla bla & {}\\
                   & & \times blabla & \notag\\
                  & = & \sum_{\lambda=-\infty}^\infty blabla bla blabla & {}
               \end{alignat}
            \end{subequations}

        \end{document}
```

[image: Resulting in:]

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `array` environment *inside* an `align` or `align*` environment. The first row of the `array` material should be left-justified, and the second row should be right-justified; the `{}` and `@{}` terms in the code below are there to help fine-tune the alignment. A (probably advantageous) side-effect of this approach is that the middle line -- i.e., the second line of the `array` -- will be a bit closer to the first line than it is to the final line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A &= \begin{array}[t]{@{}l}
     BBBBB\ CCCCCCC\\
     \multicolumn{1}{r}{{}\times DDDDD}
     \end{array}\\
  &= EEEEEEE\ FFFFF
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```